# How to modify a field that is Not null to null in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I have a field `commande_id` that is not null in a table and i want to change it to null. is it safe to change it directly in the migration or how can i do it ?

```
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE product (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, commande_id INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, price DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, image_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_D34A04AD82EA2E54 (commande_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add nullable=true to the yours Entity field, see example:

```php
class Entity 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="bot_location", type="point", nullable=true)
     */
    private ?Point $location = null;
}
```

after that you have to execute next command:

```sh
bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

it will generate new migration with SQL

Answer (score 0):

in your project directory go to `src/Entity/*Yourtablename*` and find this code

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $commande_id;
```

and add  `nullable=true` to this code

your entity code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
```

after this, change your database column settings manually,
i do that by phpmyadmin.

in your Controller when you want to save a new row and *commande_id* is null
just do this :

```
use App\Entity\Yourtablename;
$yourtablename = new Yourtablename();
if ($commande_id){
    $yourtablename->setCommandeId($commande_id);
}
```

good luck ;)